# WooCommerce – Display product category count within New Order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to display a simple list of all the categories within a new order that comes through, and the number of items in the order within that category. So something along the lines of:

Spray Cans – 3
Accessories – 2
Markers – 5
etc

This is what I've tried so far but obviously it just shows the total of products in the category and not just relating to this order.

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $items ) {

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $items->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' ); 

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo $term->name;
    echo ' - ';
    echo $term->count;
    echo '</li>';
    echo $term = count( $order->get_items() );
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will list the product categories within the WC Order with the count for each of them and at the end you will have the count of order items:

```
    $items = $order->get_items();// Get Order Items

    $terms = $term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop thriugh order items
    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        // Get the product categoory terms (array of WP_Term oblects)
        $item_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' ); 

        // Loop through the product category terms
        foreach( $item_terms as $term ) {
            $term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // add the term ID in an array
            $terms[ $term->term_id ] = $term->name; // array of term ids / term names pairs
        }
    }
    // Get an array with the count by term Id
    $terms_count = array_count_values( $term_ids );

    // Formatting for output
    $html = '<ul class="order-terms-count">';

    // loop through the terms count (array)
    foreach( $terms_count as $term_id => $count ) {
        // Format the term name with the count
        $html .= '<li>' . $terms[$term_id] . ' - ' . $count . '</li>';
    }

    // output
    echo '</ul>' . $html  . '<p>Order items - ' . count( $items ) . '</p>';
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the code has caused an error message. I'm adding the code within the email-order-details.php file if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I actually managed to tweak the existing code slightly to get the correct results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that worked for me if anyone needs it.

```
<ul class="count">
    <?php
    $category_count = [];
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item){
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );
        foreach($terms as $term){
            if(isset($category_count[$term->name]) && !empty($category_count[$term->name])){
                $category_count[$term->name] += (int)$item->get_quantity();
            }else{
                $category_count[$term->name] = (int)$item->get_quantity();
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($category_count as $name => $count){
        echo '<li>'.$name.' - '.$count.'</li>';
    }
    ?>
    
<p>Total Products: <?php echo $items_count = count( $order->get_items() ); ?></p>
    
</ul>
```